# UI for querying large sets of non-cloud financial data

Tags: user-interface, bigdata, financial

We have a large amount of financial data, stored locally, and cloud is not an option for us right now. We need to give a non-technical user, a way to run a few standard queries, with the results of those being stored in a file.

We can definitely write something in-house, a web page through which user enters the query and corresponding parameters, that creates a job, that queries the data and writes it to a file, and lets the user know when its done.

However, I feel there might be something that already performs similar tasks.  is there a package/tech out there, that provides a UI for querying large sets of findata and dumps results into a file?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data stored? In a database or files? What kind of queries do you want to run? SQL?

From your description of "large data" and Web UI, my immediate thoughts are Hadoop HDFS  for data storage and Hive for queries and maybe Hue for a web frontend.